# Parallelized + Parameterized threads with random execution order for each thread

Tags: java, junit

I've got a class which runs my tests in parallel with parameters. But to check for concurrency problems I want to execute the tests in a random order. 
Eg. test1 - test2 - test3 on the first thread and test2 - test1 - test3 on the second thread. (I think you got the point)

This is the code I'm currently working with and I already found some examples using BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters but changing Parameterized to BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters did obviously not work for me.

Thus my question is: how can I make each thread execute the test in a random order?

Hope you guys can give me some pointers...

```
public class Parallelized extends Parameterized
{

    private static class ThreadPoolScheduler implements RunnerScheduler
    {
        private ExecutorService executor; 

        public ThreadPoolScheduler()
        {
            String threads = System.getProperty("junit.parallel.threads", "16");
            int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(threads);
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        }

        @Override
        public void finished()
        {
            executor.shutdown();
            try
            {
                executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException exc)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void schedule(Runnable childStatement)
        {
            executor.submit(childStatement);
        }
    }

    public Parallelized(Class klass) throws Throwable
    {
        super(klass);
        setScheduler(new ThreadPoolScheduler());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get this to work, and a test fails, how would you reproduce the problem? Between the test randomization and the multithreading issues, the failure would be hard to reproduce. I suggest looking at test frameworks that are designed to help find concurrency issues

Comment: It is mainly about detecting the issues. 
The log will help us reproduce any occurring errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution which is fairly simple:

All you need is a ParametersRunnerFactory which creates Runners of type `BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters`.
To randomize the test order for each runner you only have to override `computeTestMethods()` and shuffle the list of methods.

To use your created RunnerFactory, you have to add `@Parameterized.UseParametersRunnerFactory(Parallelized.RunnerFactory.class)` right below the `@RunWith(Parallelized.class)` in each class you would like to use the randomized execution order.

**Note:** If don't add this annotation junit will use the default runner and not your custom runner -> no change.

```
public static class RunnerFactory implements ParametersRunnerFactory {
    @Override
    public org.junit.runner.Runner createRunnerForTestWithParameters(TestWithParameters test) throws InitializationError {
        return new CustomRunnerWithParameters(test);
    }

}

public static class CustomRunnerWithParameters extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters {
    private final Object[] parameters;

    @Override
    protected List<FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {
        List<FrameworkMethod> tests = new ArrayList<FrameworkMethod>(super.computeTestMethods());
        Collections.shuffle(tests);
        return tests;
    }

    public CustomRunnerWithParameters(TestWithParameters test) throws InitializationError {
        super(test);
        parameters = test.getParameters().toArray(new Object[test.getParameters().size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public Object createTest() throws Exception {
        return getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor().newInstance(parameters);
    }
}
```

Edit after Aroidans comment:

I've forgot to add that I'm using an overwritten getChildren method in my custom runner extending Parameterized to shuffle the execution order of the tests. But his answer is valid, too.

```
    @Override
    protected List<Runner> getChildren() {
        ArrayList<Runner> runner = new ArrayList<>(super.getChildren());
        if (NUM_THREADS > 1) {
            Collections.shuffle(runner);
        }
        return runner;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to randomize the order of the parameterized tests is to do a shuffle on the collection with the parameters.

Using the Fibonacci sample test as an example.

```
@Parameters(name= "{index}: fib[{0}]={1}")
public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
    Iterable<Object[]> tests = Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 },{ 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 } });
    Collections.shuffle((List<?>) tests);
    return tests;
}
```

This randomizes the order in which the tests using the same method are run. Using the computeTestMethod() does not work as there is only one method executing all of the tests.